# Android Studio 3 USB Debugging Offline Phone

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have upgrade my android studio to version 3.0. After this I have a problem to all devices (device is already in developer mode and USB debugging is On). What is the process to allow my device to accept debugging from android studio?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your phone to your pc and you have USB debugging enabled. You get a pop up on your phone if you accept the connected pc to acces your phone, this you have to accept  first and than it should work.

Comment: this pop up don't show in my device !! i don't know where is the problem